# Developing for ASP.NET + MS Access from Mono in Linux

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, mono, monodevelop

My main developing platform is an Ubuntu desktop but one of my projects requires to develop a web application that currently is running on an MS Windows machine with MS Access as backend.  Customer is unlikely to change their platform and I am not willing right now to invest (yet) in an MS development environment.

Currently I am running Mono over my LAMP environment, hoping than when I port to production I will have little trouble with their IIS + ASP.NET implementation. (sub question. Is this naïve?), but then I have to plug with their database.

I can think on several approaches:

1. To have support the `.mdb` files directly from Mono (and hope that this works both in my Linux development system and in the MS production system).
2. To install in Ubuntu a DB server that serves as an interface to Mono for the `.mdb` files much as MS Access does for ASP.NET.  Are there any?
3. To use a different DBMS and then migrate and translate in production.
4. To choose a different DBMS that works both in Linux and Windows, and replace MS Access in production.

Which would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

So what you are seeking is

(1) A method of reading the MDB files, so you can migrate them into MySQL or some other Linux DB.
(2) A Linux Development environment in which you can write ASP.NET pages?

If I misunderstand you then please correct.

If I do understand you - then I have to say that you're making life really hard for yourself.  You aren't going to get a linux-based development environment that can produce portable .NET code that you can "drop in" - not unless this is something you've been doing for a long time and you know porting conventions (and differences between Mono and vanilla .NET) like the back of your hand.

"Use the right tool for the right job".  I would look into a Win7 Virtual Machine and do your development in there.  You can also delegate/sub the job out to someone else that has a windows dev environment.

If you are determined to tackle this then check out mdbtools (http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/).  If this is a product that you intend on supporting for your client, then you are going to have to get it over to a LAMP setup - it sounds like that is your comfort zone.  You don't want to be trying to support something you are not equipped to support.